# php Imagick - why does it save in that folder?

Tags: php, xampp, imagick

I am using Imagick for the first time and discovered ununderstandable behaviour; consider a code:

```
public function cropImage() {
    $dir = "/";
    $image = new Imagick ( $this->file['tmp_name'] );
    $w = $image->getImageWidth();
    $h = $image->getImageHeight();
    $image -> cropImage( $w, $h, 0, 0 );
    $image -> writeImage(  $dir.'kalreg.jpg');
}
```

It saves file correctly but... in my `c:\xampp\apache`. But my `/` directory is `c:\xampp\htdocs\`. Also saving a file like:

```
    $image -> writeImage('kalreg.jpg');
```

meaning without directory it also saves to `c:\apache\`. I'd expect that it would save in directory where my script is located. 
Is ther ea way to change it somehow to scripts base directory or `c:\xampp\htdocs` ?

Comment: "my / directory is c:\xampp\htdocs\". No, this is a directory named "/", relative to Apache's working directory. I would expect this to be an illegal name on Windows, actually.

Comment: The script's directory is stored in the `__DIR__` constant.